# The same instance in different classes C++

Tags: c++, class, reference, instance

test.h:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

};

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();

};

class C
{
public:
    C();
    ~C();

};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

A::A()
{
    C c1;
}
A::~A()
{

}


B::B()
{
    //Here, too, must be "c1"
}
B::~B()
{

}

C::C()
{

}
C::~C()
{

}
```

How can I access from class B to an instance of class C?

1. I read something about the composition, but did not understand what it is.
2. Copying does not work, because class C stores certain data that is constantly changing. I need to change them from class A and B.
3. Singleton also does not fit

Thanks!

Comment: Pass it as reference or pointer?

Comment: do you know difference between class and instance of class?

Comment: `A` or `B` (or both) should store a reference to `C`.  e.g. `B::B(C& c) : c1(c) {}`

Comment: You need a pointer. Maybe even a [shared pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: Where are the declarations for the classes? Otherwise I will have to resort to the stars?

Comment: Edited post. I wanted to show a simple example

Answer (score 1):

In your code there isn't any object of class `C` that could be shared; the only instance of class `C` you define is a local variable within constructor of `A`, and this object is unaccessible to others (and will be destroyed once this constructor finishes).

A simple way would be to define one global variable of type `C` and use it within other translation units (or the same unit):

```
// c.h
class C
{   public:
    C(int val) : someVal(val) {};
    int someVal;
};
extern C c1; // declare c1

// c.cpp: 
C c1(0);  // define c1 once in the program

// a.cpp
#include "c.h" // import the declaration of c1 (will not redefine it!)
A::A() {
    c1.someVal = 5;
}

// b.cpp
#include "c.h"
B::B() {
    c1.someVal = 10;
}
```